# Spring batch integration remote chunking timeout for manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-integration

In spring batch remote chunking, consider a situation where the worker consumers are not available. In that case the manager publishes number of items equal to the throttle limit and waits for the reply from the workers. I have the `receiveTimeout` for the `MessagingTemplate` set to `5000`. This [loop](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.java#L98-L100) from `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter` `write()` is running infinitely because after every 5 seconds, the `MessagingTemplate` `receive()` timeout and returns null [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.java#L225). It doesn't perform anything if the result is null and thus falls into infinite loop.

In this scenario, the Job remains in an `UNKNOWN` state. Is there any way to perform the timeout from the manager end if it doesn't get any reply from the workers for some amount of time and mark the job as failed?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to perform the timeout from the manager end if it doesn't get any reply from the workers for some quite an amount of time and mark the job as failed?

You can set the `maxWaitTimeouts` on the `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter` parameters for that.

Comment: `maxWaitTimeouts` is applicable during `afterStep`. But this is happening during the `write()` which runs into an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue? There is a remote-chunking sample with an embedded broker here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking. If you manage to create a sample that reproduces the issue with it, please open an issue on GitHub and add a reference to this SO question and I will take a look in details.